# Reading user's posts to pages

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

For a given Facebook user, is there a possibility to read all posts that he's made to any pages? On FB web, these can be found in the activity log, but so far I couldn't find a method to get them via API.

Both `/user/posts` and `/user/feeds` only contain status and profile updates, not posts to pages. I know I can read `/page/feed` and use paging to find this user's posts for any page the user likes, but how about those he doesn't?

Comment: Would {page-id}/tagged help? https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/page/feed

It does say all the 'posts to page', so I imagine you can filter it out to only user posts, there is a limit of 250, though.

Comment: @matrixanomaly well, it may be better than `page/feed`, but it still doesn't solve that I don't know which pages the user has posted to

Comment: Ah, sorry didn't realize you need to know which pages the user has posted to since I thought you only wanted to read user's post to a specific set of pages. Perhaps edit your question to be more explicit about it? The Graph API is fairly restrictive imo.

Answer (score 0):

No, outside of FQL, there is nothing in the API that accomplishes this. I'd imagine this to be a pretty data intensive call with minimal use cases however, so I don't think this will be introduced anytime soon.